# How Can I Get Highest Degree For an Employee Using Following Tables?

Tags: postgresql

I have an `Employee` Table:

```
ID      Name  
1        Jhon
2        Mark
```

And an `Education` Table:

```
ID       Degree              Emp_ID
1         High School         1
2         Bachelor            1
3         Masters             1
4         Bachelor            1
5         High School         2
6         PHD                 2
7         Masters             2
```

Considering that another bachelor is added for Jhon after his master's, and a masters degree is added after the PHD for Mark, considering this concept I want to retrieve the highest degree for each employee as follows:

```
Name     Degree
jhon       Master
Mark       PHD
```

I am using PostgreSQL.
Please kindly help.
thanks in advance

Comment: I tried to generate a copy of Education table and add a sortby column to it and assign each degree a unique number then it worked, but i dont want to do this using this method which is copying of table.

Comment: @peach This was awesome it worked, Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select x.name, x.degree from (
select 
    em.name,
    ed.degree,
    row_number() over (partition by em.name order by
        case 
        when ed.degree = 'High School' then 1 
        when ed.degree = 'Bachelor' then 2 
        when ed.degree = 'Masters' then 3
        when ed.degree = 'PHD' then 4 
        else null 
        end
    desc) as degree_rank
from employee em
left join education ed
    on em.id = ed.emp_id 
) x
where x.degree_rank = 1
```